# Memory Error subtracting values in sorted list made from dictionary values

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, memory

I have a dictionary with a Ref_ID for street link as the key and sequenced stops on that street as the values. I want to determine if the stops are out of sequence. I  have a dict consisting of items like so 1234567:[5,10,15,35,] where the array represents the sequences on a given block.

I am using a while loop with in a for loop that iterates through each value until the count = 2, appending the values to a tuple and then subtracting the first value from the second. I d the difference is greater than 40 I wan the program to store the link in another list under the route it's associated with.

I am presently getting a memory error when running the script:

```
eCheck = []
oCheck = []

for key, value in eLinks.items():
    for k in value:
        eValues.append(k)
        eList = sorted(eValues)
    for i in eList:
        eValuescount = 0
        while eValuescount < 2:
            eCheck.append(k)
            eItemscount += 1
        x = eValues[1] - eValues[0]
        print x
        if x > 40:
            eCheckStreet.append(key)

print "Route ", route, " even side"
for link in eCheckStreet:
    print link
```

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 323, in RunScript
    debugger.run(codeObject, __main__.__dict__, start_stepping=0)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\debugger\__init__.py", line 60, in run
    _GetCurrentDebugger().run(cmd, globals,locals, start_stepping)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\debugger\debugger.py", line 654, in run
    exec cmd in globals, locals
  File "N:\Python\Completed scripts\Check_Sequences.py", line 1, in <module>
    import arcpy
MemoryError
```

Comment: Could you provide sample input and desired output?

Comment: I assume this `while eValuescount < 2:` causes an infinite loop, as `eValuescount` is never changed in the while loop.